# Why can't I find PackageMaker?

Tags: xcode

As far as I know, the PackageMaker should be part of "Auxiliary tools for Xcode" and can be downloaded from https://developer.apple.com/downloads. However I cannot see the "Auxiliary tools for Xcode" download (using free developer account).

What am I missing?
Is it because of the free account?
Where can I find the PackageMaker?

Comment: I've also a free account but I see 3 different Auxiliary tools for Xcode (Feb & July 2012) + 1 for Xcode DP

Comment: I don't understand why I can't see those downloads. Maybe it has something to do with profile or account settings or...

Comment: Hum, tested with a free developer account and the software doesn't shows either, so it's not a specific issue of yours.

Comment: Which navigator do you use ?

Comment: I use Safari Version 6.0.3 (7536.28.10).

Comment: Tested again, and it's shown now. Weird. Give it another try, @Ted.

Comment: Still no luck but I'll keep trying.

Comment: Try opening the link directly, which is: [Auxiliary Tools](http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/auxiliary_tools_for_xcode__late_july_2012/xcode44auxtools6938114a.dmg)

Comment: It says "Your session has expired.", although I am logged in to the https://developer.apple.com.

Comment: Hmm... today the download is available. Weird. No idea why it took some time to appear. Thank you all.

Answer (score 4):

Download Auxiliary Tools for Xcode - Late July 2012 from http://developer.apple.com/downloads - it works on OS X 10.11 fine.

Answer (score 3):

Auxiliary Tools can definitely be downloaded at the link you provided. However PackageMaker is no longer included with the current Auxiliary Tools. See [this answer for alternatives](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/167522/packagemaker-alternative)

Comment: "Auxiliary tools for Xcode 8" doesn't seem to be available? It seems that latest one is "Auxiliary tools for Xcode 7", or am I missing anything? Or does the "Auxiliary tools for Xcode 7" works with Xcode 8?

Comment: It's now called Additional Tools for Xcode http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Additional_Tools_for_Xcode_8.2/Additional_Tools_for_Xcode_8.2.dmg

Comment: PackageMaker is not in Additional Tools for Xcode, either.

Comment: PackageMaker is still available from Apple directly in late 2023; it's contained in "Auxiliary Tools for Xcode - Late July 2012": https://developer.apple.com/download/all/?q=Auxiliary%20Tools%20for%20Xcode%20-%20Late%20July%202012 . Here is the direct download link (must be signed in to developer account to access either link): https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/auxiliary_tools_for_xcode__late_july_2012/xcode44auxtools6938114a.dmg . The PackageMaker version is reported as 3.0.6 (201). See also [Fix-PackageMaker-APFS](https://github.com/chris1111/Fix-PackageMaker-APFS).