# PackageMaker alternative?

Tags: macos, osx-server

I am looking for something to create .pkg files to use with System Image Utility. The old school PackageMaker that was included in Xcode Aux tools make be causing errors in Yosemite so I am wanting to test this with another tool.

Goal:

Create a .pkg that will contain Firefox, Chrome, other software to installing during the imaging process

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's two alternatives I'm aware of for PackageMaker that would work in this situation:

1. A third-party tool named [Packages](http://s.sudre.free.fr/Software/Packages/about.html)
2. Apple's [pkgbuild](https://www.unix.com/man-page/osx/1/pkgbuild/) and [productbuild](https://www.unix.com/man-page/osx/1/productbuild/) tools working together.

If you're planning to add packages to a NetInstall set, you should be aware that Apple made an undocumented change in Yosemite. If you add any additional packages for installation as part of a Yosemite OS install/upgrade (like you would with NetInstall), they must all be distribution-style flat packages.

Bundle-style packages (like those created by PackageMaker) will not work when added to a Yosemite OS install/upgrade and component-style flat packages also will not work.

For more information, see [Further note on additional packages and Yosemite](https://github.com/munki/createOSXinstallPkg#further-note-on-additional-packages-and-yosemite).